# Is there any way to run a Dash app in Kaggle?

Tags: python, localhost, plotly-dash, kaggle

I've been working on a project involving Dash from plotly. I made small apps with jupyter-dash locally and I wanted to share my work on Kaggle but I can't run a dash app on Kaggle since I need a localhost. I didn't find any information about this issue so I'm coming here hoping that someone faced the same issue and solved it.

Thank you,
Miljan.

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

year_options = []
for year in df_cleaned['Year'].unique():
    year_options.append({'label':str(year), 'value':year})
year_options.append({'label':'All', 'value':'All'})
    
segment_options = []
for segment in df_cleaned['Segment'].unique():
    segment_options.append({'label':str(segment), 'value':segment})
segment_options.append({'label':'All Customers', 'value':'All Customers'})


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='year-picker',
                options=year_options,
                value='All'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='segment-picker',
                options=segment_options,
                value='All Customers')
    
    
])
@app.callback(Output(component_id='graph', component_property='figure'),
             [Input(component_id='year-picker', component_property='value'),
             Input(component_id='segment-picker', component_property='value')])
def update_figure(selected_year, selected_segment):
    
    # Data only for selected year from dropdown
    if selected_year!= 'All' and selected_segment == 'All Customers':
        filtered_df = df_cleaned[df_cleaned['Year']== int(selected_year)]
    
    elif selected_year!= 'All' and selected_segment != 'All Customers':
        filtered_df = df_cleaned[df_cleaned['Year']== int(selected_year)]
        filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df['Segment']==selected_segment]
        
    elif selected_year == 'All' and selected_segment == 'All Customers':
        filtered_df = df_cleaned.copy(deep=True)
    
    elif selected_year == 'All' and selected_segment != 'All Customers':
        filtered_df = df_cleaned[df_cleaned['Segment']==selected_segment]
        
        
    customer_country=filtered_df[['Country','Customer ID']].drop_duplicates()
    filtered_df_grouped = customer_country.groupby(['Country'])['Customer ID'].aggregate('count').reset_index().sort_values('Customer ID', ascending=False)
        
    data = go.Choropleth(
                locations = filtered_df_grouped['Country'],
                locationmode = 'country names',
                z = filtered_df_grouped['Customer ID'],
                text = filtered_df_grouped['Country'],
                colorscale = 'Rainbow',
                marker_line_color='darkgray',
                marker_line_width=0.5,
                colorbar_title = 'Customers',
                )

    layout = go.Layout(
                title_text='Our customers',
                title_x=0.5,
                geo=dict(
                    showframe=False,
                    showcoastlines=False,
                    projection_type='equirectangular'
                ),
                )

    fig_update = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

    return fig_update        
        
app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

Comment: "localhost" is just a placeholder for the machine the script is running on, equivalent to 127.0.0.1. The real question is whether the virtual machine on which your code is running on (on the Kaggle server) exposes the port to the outside world. If it does, you just need to figure out the IP of the machine and navigate to that IP with the dash port (usually 8050).

Comment: Yes, I meant server sorry. This could actually work, I'm going to look into it and get back to you. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I tried running a basic Dash app in a Kaggle notebook and got an exception. I think they blocked it.

Comment: Does you code use any special feature that regular Plotly (non-Dash) doesn't support? As far as I can tell, you have some dropdown menus as part of your plot. I myself have made a COVID-19 Data Visualization notebook on Kaggle where I use the dropdown menus with regular Plotly and don't have any issues. My notebook can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/jacobkrucinski/coronavirus-covid-19-data-extrapolation)

Comment: @Shovalt Could you do it before? I found Kaggle virtual machines' IP but nothing appeared when I ran it.

Comment: @JacobK Thank you for your notebook. Actually, I didn't know that there was a way to make your plot interactive only on Plotly. That's why I used dash components. I upvoted your notebook and I'm going to do it with only Plotly components. Thanks again!

Comment: @MiljanStojiljkovic Glad I could help! Let me know if you need any help with converting your Dash code to regular Plotly.

Comment: Also take a look it "interact": https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html
This can take care of all of your interactive needs within a notebook, with or without plotly.

Comment: @JacobK I'm going to play around with Plotly components and see what I can do with it. There's not a lot of resources on it but, it is pretty intuitive even though I'd rather use Dash! Now, I know where to ask if I struggle with it, thanks!

Comment: @Shovalt Could it's funny because I wanted to update my graph by hovering on another graph which is kind of easy with Dash but, with Plotly it's not that easy. Literally one minute before opening StackOverflow I found out about Jupiter widgets. It would be awesome if I could replicate Dash's hovering process with Plotly and Jupyter widgets. I'll try!

Comment: Oh and by the way I wanted to upvote your comments but it appears that I can't for now. Maybe it's because it's a new account. Anyway you've been very useful!